# Eloquent how to update child table value while parent table value is not change

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-4

my model relationship able to update the child value when parent table value is changed. The problem is `$model->save()` will not update the child table if parent table dont have make changes.

Product model relationship (parent)

```
public function branch()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('BranchProduct')->where('branch_product.id', 'id');
    }
```

BranchProduct model relationship (child)

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Product', 'id', 'product_id');
    }
```

Sample code

```
$instance = Product::findOrFail(1);
$instance->fill('code, price');
$instance->save();
```

Assuming child table has column `stock` and it will update the child table `stock` value when parent table `code` or `price` has changed. However, when child table `stock` value will not being update if parent value is not change.

Comment: What is the logic behind updating `stock` compared to  `code` or `price` ?

Comment: Beware that your relationships don't work like this. You don't add `hasOne` twice but only  on one relationship (the one, that does not have the foreign key). Also your naming of `branch_product` is kind of reserved wording for a many-to-many relationship between Branch and Product. On top of that, your `where(...)` condition is checking for the string `id`, which is probably not what you want. You should omit the where condition. If you want to name the columns that should be used for the relationship, you can do so within the `hasOne` function.
Also, your `fill('code, price')` doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry for the long comment. `fill`, like `update`, expects an associative array, with the array keys being the column you want  to update. You should try to follow some tutorials first and also read the documentation. Have a look at https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can use events for this purpose (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events-using-closures)

In your `Product` model, you can track the updated event and modify your child model accordingly.

```
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::updated(function ($product) {
            $product->branch->update([...]);
        });
    }
```